# SketchFlow wizard-like window

Tags: window, wizard, sketchflow

Is there a way to create a wizard-like window in SketchFlow 4?
it needs the standard prev/next buttons, and of course the "Finish" button on the last page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you having problems creating that? Sounds like a straightforward use of the prototyping features in SketchFlow. Simply link the sequence of screens together and use buttons with navigation behaviors to navigate between the screens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same thing right now.  We came at it two different ways - up to you which you prefer.

One is to use a TabControl and use the tabs as the steps of the wizard.  This means you don't have to deal with adding the nav links back and forth, but you might have trouble getting the look you're hoping for.

The other way, as Chuck mentions, is just to essentially clone each step of the wizard screen as its own individual SketchFlow screen, with just the content section changed.  Then you can link up each screen with the navigation hooks in the SketchFlow Map.

The latter is certainly more customizable, and once you get the hang of how to reuse sections of your design, tends to work better.